# AWS Instance Serial Number of the machine

Tags: windows-10, serial-number

Do AWS instances have a serial number like that on the back of a laptop? Is there a way to get it? I am running a windows 10 on AWS. I am looking to add the AWS Instance as a "Company Owned Inventory" in Google Admin(Gsuite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Identify EC2 Windows instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-serial-console.html):

> You can get the system UUID and look for the presence of the characters "EC2" in the beginning octet of the UUID. This method to determine whether a system is an EC2 instance is quick but potentially inaccurate because there is a small chance that a system that is not an EC2 instance could have a UUID that starts with these characters. Furthermore, EC2 instances using SMBIOS 2.4 might represent the UUID in little-endian format, therefore the "EC2" characters do not appear at the beginning of the UUID.

It states that using the following command should get the system UUID:

```
wmic path win32_computersystemproduct get uuid
```